# Screen Coordinates With CGAffineTransform

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I m using Gesture touch function to Rotate resize my image. Now what i want to do is that when the image hit a certain X,Y point it disappears from the view.

When i worked with CGpoint it worked fine.

How do i gether the (x y) coordinates from CGTransform Matrix

The Code i m using currently is

```
- (void)updateOriginalTransformForTouches:(NSSet *)touches 
{
    if ([touches count] > 0) {
        CGAffineTransform incrementalTransform = [self incrementalTransformWithTouches:touches];
        [self setConstrainedTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(originalTransform, incrementalTransform)];
        originalTransform = self.transform;
    }
}

// At start, store the touch begin points and set an original transform
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    [[self superview] bringSubviewToFront:self];
    NSMutableSet *currentTouches = [[[event touchesForView:self] mutableCopy] autorelease];
    [currentTouches minusSet:touches];
    if ([currentTouches count] > 0) {
        [self updateOriginalTransformForTouches:currentTouches];
        [self cacheBeginPointForTouches:currentTouches];
    }
    [self cacheBeginPointForTouches:touches];
}

// During movement, update the transform to match the touches
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    CGAffineTransform incrementalTransform = [self incrementalTransformWithTouches:[event touchesForView:self]];
    [self setConstrainedTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(originalTransform, incrementalTransform)];

    NSLog(@"%f",incrementalTransform.tx);
    NSLog(@"%f",incrementalTransform.ty);

    if (incrementalTransform.tx == 44 && incrementalTransform.ty == 281) {
        NSLog(@"dvvd");
    }
}

// Finish by removing touches, handling double-tap requests
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    [self updateOriginalTransformForTouches:[event touchesForView:self]];
    [self removeTouchesFromCache:touches];

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        if (touch.tapCount >= 2) {
            [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
        }
    }

    NSMutableSet *remainingTouches = [[[event touchesForView:self] mutableCopy] autorelease];
    [remainingTouches minusSet:touches];
    [self cacheBeginPointForTouches:remainingTouches];
}// Redirect cancel to ended
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    [self touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i would like to answer my own question

i have been searching for various methods to perform my tack last night i found PanGestures which will be more then handy for my task

so [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more) is the link which i use it

It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to determine where the view's rect is in the current coordinate system?  If so,

```
CGRect transformedFrame = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(self.frame, incrementalTransform);
```

Comment: I brief it further to u... I have few images on my screen (WithOut UIImageView) these images can be resize and rotate (with the code i provided) now what i m trying to do is that i want to delete any of the image on view. For that to happen the user has to drag it to a certain location where there will be another image (which will be fixed t o the view ) of a dustbin (lets say the location of that is (100,100) if the user drags that image to this coordinate the image get deleted from the view///